# how spark determines dataframe size when auto broadcast is enabled

Tags: apache-spark

I know that spark can broadcast the one of source if source size is lessthan the broadcast threshold. But i am unable find it how spark determines the size of the source to compare with threshold. Because spark is an lazy evaluation. the source data will not be available while generating logical and physical plan.

i have gone SizeEstimater but this is just calculate the jvm object size.

so can you please help to understand 
how spark calculates source size to determine whether i have to use broadcast or not in physical plan. where source data is not yet read.